# No data available in table with successful response

Tags: jquery, html, json, datatable, datatables

I checked the network monitor in Firefox and it says that I successfully got the Json data. From the spring guide, it should be:

```
{
  "id": 37658,
  "content": "Hello, World!"
}
```

But I get `no data available in table` on my datatable. Am I missing something?

Full code at [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PrqUJdN5p3hmAHdQkjtH)

Table:

```
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width: 100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
```

Script:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "ajax" : {
            "dataType" : 'json',
            "contentType" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "url" : "http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting",
            "dataSrc" : "",
        },
        columns: [{
            data: "id",
            name: "id",
            title: "Id"
            }, 
         {
            data: "content",
            name: "content",
            title: "content"
        }]
    });         
});

</script>
```

Comment: The returned JSON should be an array of objects, you only return an object.

Comment: Thanks. I used an api with an array of objects and now i get the following error: "DataTables warning: table id=example - Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0."

See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/pg04e9ciREl9311E24we

Comment: Please do the minimal effort to read the documentation -> **https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html** You need to declare the columns; how should DT know where to put the content of the received JSON?
 Have forked your plunkr to demonstrate  -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/8Cm9Vi2W05xIuNhH272k?p=preview**

Answer (score 0):

My column syntax was incorrect. Its fixed below with some added parameters:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            "ajax" : {
                "dataType" : 'json',
                "contentType" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "url" : "http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting",
                "dataSrc" : "",
            },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id"},
            { "data": "content"}
        ]
        });         
    }); 
</script>
```